# Exception on GetRowCellValue function in DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, exception, devexpress

I'm trying to execute following code. My grid contains a row. But NullReference exception occures. Could you plz tell me the problem with my code?

```
tblItemCode = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(0, gridView1.Columns["Item Code"]).ToString();
```

Comment: `gridView1`, or `gridView1.Columns["Item Code"]` or the return value of the call to `GetRowCellValue(..)` is null. If it is the latter then the NPE is from calling `ToString()` ... Too many reasons for this to fail without more context. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if `GridView` has rows / selected rows and only then do the assignment:

```
 if (gridView1.RowCount > 0)
 {
      if (gridView1.GetSelectedRows().Count() > 0) //optional check
      {
          string tblItemCode = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(0, gridView1.Columns["Item Code"]).ToString();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions...

1. Drop the ToString() at the end and put the value in an object (in debug mode).
2. If it still throws an error, then that hints to me that the "Item Code" column doesn't exist.  My guess is that it's actually named something similar but not exact, perhaps "ItemCode."  If you are mapping to a List, that's likely.

Put in some simple debug code to see what the actual column names are:

```
        foreach (var col in grdPartMasterView.Columns)
        {
            // Put a break point here and
            // take a peek at the properties of "col"
        }
```